# mysql select for greatest value

Tags: mysql, select

One table

```
MODEL(IDMODEL inc., NAME text)
```

One table

```
DOC(IDDOC inc., NAME text, RELEASE numeric, IDMODEL numeric)
```

Records in DOC verify that `DOC.IDMODEL == MODEL.IDMODEL.`

I want to select all the records from `DOC` with the greatest value of `RELEASE`.

Datas from MODEL :

```
"1" "specification"
"2" "cahier de test"
```

Datas from DOC :

```
iddoc   name        release idmodel
"1" "doc 1.1"   "1" "1"
"2" "doc 1.2"   "2" "1"
"3" "doc 2.1"   "1" "2"
"4" "doc 2.2"   "2" "2"
"5" "doc 2.3"   "3" "2"  > required
"6" "doc 1.3"   "3" "1"
"7" "doc 1.4"   "4" "1"  > required
"8" "doc 2 bis.1"   "1" "2"
"9" "doc 2 bis.2"   "2" "2"
"10" "doc 2 bis.3"  "3" "2"  > required
```

Can you help me for the SELECT commands ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way by using subselect:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DOC 
WHERE release=(
    SELECT max(release) FROM DOC
    )
```

Or

```
 SELECT * from DOC ORDER BY release DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should return the rows that you need:

```
SELECT doc.*
FROM
  doc INNER JOIN (SELECT idmodel, MAX(release) As max_release
                  FROM doc
                  GROUP BY idmodel) mx
  ON doc.idmodel = mx.idmodel AND doc.release=max_release
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6316/1).